# Force acting on photons?

Tags: optics, visible-light, speed-of-light, refraction

We know that when a ray of light goes from denser to rarer medium, it bends away from the normal due to increase in its speed. But that means it bas been accelarated and a force acts on it. Am I right? Please explain.

Comment: Keep in mind that a "ray of light" isn't a physical object, it's a wave. Individual photons are not being redirected in the way the wave as a whole is.

Comment: This may be of some interest: https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1510/1510.06227.pdf

Comment: I want to ask a question. Does light behave as wave or particle during refraction?

Comment: Wave. Read the dupe candidate.